# Можно ли запустить php приложение на хостинге для сайта?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, парсер, хостинг, бот

Имеется ввиду, например, написать бота или постоянно работающий парсер.

Посмотрел хостинги для приложений - как-то неадекватно по ценам получается. Да, есть смысл платить, если зарабатываешь на этом. Но не на стадии теста, имхо.

Comment: На хостинге как правило стоит лимит на время выполнения = 30 секунд. Тестируй дома, а потом бери VDP/VPS. Не так уж и дорого. Тем более если зарабатываешь на этом.

Comment: Работа по крону, как вариант....

Comment: До пятисот рублей в месяц на VDS - не так уж и неадекватно